# Elif statement always responding with if

Tags: python

Example

```
Good=1
Bad=2
print("How was your day?")
input()
if Good:
    Print("That's nice.")
elif Bad: 
       Print("That's unfortunate")
```

For some reason this program always respond with "That's nice." even when I say bad.

Answer (score 1):

`if Good` is always `True`, you have to assign input to a variable and then compare:

```
inp = input()
if inp == Good:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You aquired the input value, but did not assign it to a variable.

You should introduce a new variable (let's call it `answer`):

```
good=1
bad=2
print("How was your day?")
answer = input()  ## <-- changed
if answer == good:  ## <-- changed
    print("That's nice.")
elif answer == bad:  ## <-- changed
    print("That's unfortunate")
```

Comment: If you keep `good` and `bad` assigned to integers, `answer` will never be equal to either one.

Comment: It actually depends on the python version OP is using, I believe. I'm assuming they are using python 2, and it works there :)

Comment: If that is true, than `raw_input()` should be used.

Comment: If OP is using python 2 and wants to read strings then yes. The `input()` function, instead, is basically just `eval(raw_input())`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the input value to a variable.Try the following code:

```
Good = 1
Bad = 2
print('How was your day?')
inputVal = int(input())
if inputVal == Good:
    print("That's nice.")
elif inputVal == Bad:
    print("That's unfortunate")
```

Input:1
Output:That's nice.
Input:2
Output:That's unfortunate